# sqlite syntaxerror only in php

Tags: php, sqlite

i wanna create a toplist of my level system, and now i try to select three columns of my sqlitedb `points`, `userName` and `lvl`. And now i want to generate a rank of these colums orderd by the `points`.

In my nodejs script (with better-sqlite3) and in a test addon from Visual Studio Code the syntax below completely works fine but I get the following Error in php: `Warning: SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 17, near "(": syntax error in /var/www/html/req/load.php on line 10`

here's my sqlite syntax: `SELECT`points`,`userName`,`lvl`, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY`points`DESC) AS`rank`FROM`accounts`LIMIT 10;`

```php
//code snip from php
    $db = new SQLite3('db/stats.db');

    $result = $db->query('SELECT `points`, `userName`, `lvl`, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY `points` DESC) AS `rank` FROM `accounts` LIMIT 10;');
    while ($row = $result->fetchArray()) {
        echo var_dump($row);
    }
```

and i wonder why `SELECT`points`,`userName`,`lvl`FROM`accounts`LIMIT 10;` completely works fine.

Is there an extension, that I've to unlock or install?

Thanks for help :D

*~ Player_Schark*

Comment: You're probably using an old version of sqlite that doesn't support window functions.

Comment: I use `sqlite 3.16.2`

Comment: how can i update this? `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` won't work

Comment: Depends on if PHP uses its own bundled version of sqlite or an OS-provided library version. The former might require upgrading PHP, the latter might require replacing the OS one with a newer version (Or just putting it in /usr/local/lib). Either way you'll want Sqlite 3.25 or newer.

Comment: ok so i my server (debian9 'stretch') says that my version `3.16.2` is the newest version, but if i look to the release history (https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html) i can see that the current version is `3.28.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i solved the problem.
The problem was, that the default debian package sqlite3 is on version `3.16.X` but window functions are stil supported since version `3.25.0`

so, i added `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main` into my sources.list file (`/etc/apt/sources.list`) https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/

after that i installed the package from the backports https://packages.qa.debian.org/s/sqlite3.html with
`sudo apt-get -t stretch-backports install sqlite3`

i restarted my apache2 server and i works! :D